# How do I place an iframe and a div side by side?

Tags: html, iframe

beginner HTMLer here. trying to do an edit for the churches website. we use a dacast stream and chatwing one over top of the over

I want to place them side by side. HELP.

Comment: "<p>
<iframe src="http://viewer.dacast.com/beta/b/2489/c/28044" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="chatwing-embedded-60cc3711-65cc-4a8c-a06b-5feb980de6ea"></div>

Comment: Add your code to the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely need to use CSS in order to do this correctly. If you are unfamiliar with CSS as a beginner, you must look it up to be effective.

In HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>Content</div>
    <iframe src="urlhere"></iframe>
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
#wrapper div, iframe {
    float: left;
}
```

But if you cannot use CSS, than you can use a table. This method is not recommended.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><div>Content</div></td>
    <td><iframe src="dacast"></iframe></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yea I think I can use css, but UGH

Comment: I realized I can make the chatwing an iframe as well, but the boxes still appear one overtop of the other